# jQuery Mobile Slider Input Not Wide Enough

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Could someone tell me how to increase the width of the input area of a jQuery Mobile slider without throwing off the rest of the control's elements. The input area is clipping large numbers.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="page1" data-role="page">
        <header data-role="header" data-theme="a"       data-position="fixed">

        </header>                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="trDesiredAnnuityPayment">
                    <label id="PremiumText" for="txtDesiredAnnuityPayment">Desired Payment</label>
                    <input type="range" id="txtDesiredAnnuityPayment" name="txtDesiredAnnuityPayment"
                  step="1000" value="2088880" min="1000" max="5000000">
                </div>  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
#txtDesiredAnnuityPayment{
    width:auto;
}
```

Tested in google chrome.